# CSS not loading in the front and backend after installing via Installatron Script

Tags: magento2

[404 not found in the backend as well as front-end Console Errors in magento2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5NIF.png)

I have installed fresh magento2. I am getting this attached errors in the console. files not found 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below command in command line.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

then give permission proper permission to var,pub and generate folder.After doing all task check your problem it has been resolved.